# Can anyone help me with adding a slump into rbacon? It looks simple but it keeps throwing an error

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm using rbacon to create an age model. I am using the default core that comes with the package "MSB2K". The documentation says to add a slump, insert the code: slump=c(). Requires pairs of depths, e.g., slump=c(10,15,60,67) for slumps at 67-60 and 15-10 cm core depth.

I try the following code but it gives me an error

```
Bacon("MSB2K", slump = c(30, 34))
```

Error in if (!is.na(hiatus.depths)[1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have zero domain knowledge here, but technically, it appears that to use the `slump` argument, one has to pair it will the `hiatus.depths` argument, and the latter has to be within the range of the former.  For example,

```
Bacon("MSB2K", slump=c(30,34), hiatus.depths=32)
```

will work. I suppose the details are in [the associated primary literature](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1339616472).